# Аналог "служб" android на iOS?

Tags: background-task, objective-c, ios

В общем, есть мобильный клиент, получающий данные с сервера. В андроиде есть так называемые службы - процессы, работающие в бэкграунде в независимости от самого приложения (на сколько я понял). Где найти туториолы по аналогичной штуке в iOS? Нужно реализовать автоматическую подкачку данных в то время, когда приложением не пользуются.

Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Comment: [Руководство по работе с Apple Push Notification Service](http://habrahabr.ru/company/ruswizards/blog/156811/).

Answer (score 3):

iOS application background modes и конкретно iOS 7 background fetching, iOS 7 silent push notification - когда приходит пуш с сервера, приложению дается возможность обновить контент, после этого показать уведомление типа "хэээй, вышли новые крутые трейлеры к фильмам" когда контент уже будет загружен

http://www.g8production.com/post/72656082173/ios7-multitasking-silent-notifications
http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios
http://habrahabr.ru/post/208434/